How to convert Figma tokens Json file to use in Flutter app as a Theme Data
I have a four Json files contains style tokens, each file has the same structure but for different brand.
how i can convert those files to dart files to use theme as a different Theme Data depending on the brand.
this is the structure for the Json files:
{
  "fontFamilyDefault": "Metric",
  "fontWeightDefault": "Regular",
  "fontWeightEmphasis": "Medium",
  "fontWeightSubtle": "Light",
  "fontBodyS": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Regular","lineHeight":22,"fontSize":20,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none"},
  "fontBodyL": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Light","lineHeight":26,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","fontSize":24},
  "fontBodyEmphasisS": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Medium","lineHeight":22,"fontSize":20,"paragraphSpacing":0,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none"},
  "fontBodyEmphasisL": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Medium","lineHeight":26,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","fontSize":24,"paragraphSpacing":110},
  "fontPreambleS": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Light","lineHeight":26,"fontSize":22,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none"},
  "fontPreambleL": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Light","lineHeight":31,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","fontSize":26,"paragraphSpacing":110},
  "fontLabelS": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Regular","lineHeight":22,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","fontSize":20,"letterSpacing":2},
  "fontLabelEmphasisS": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Medium","lineHeight":22,"fontSize":20,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","letterSpacing":2},
  "fontLabelEmphasisL": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Medium","lineHeight":26,"fontSize":24,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","letterSpacing":2},
  "fontLabelL": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Light","lineHeight":26,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","fontSize":24,"letterSpacing":2,"paragraphSpacing":110},
  "fontSubheadingS": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Medium","lineHeight":26,"fontSize":24,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none"},
  "fontSubheadingL": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Regular","lineHeight":34,"fontSize":31,"letterSpacing":0,"paragraphSpacing":0,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none"},
  "fontSubheadingXl": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Regular","lineHeight":41,"letterSpacing":0,"paragraphSpacing":0,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","fontSize":37},
  "fontHeadingS": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Medium","lineHeight":30,"fontSize":27,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none"},
  "fontHeadingL": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Regular","lineHeight":41,"fontSize":37,"letterSpacing":0,"paragraphSpacing":0,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none"},
  "fontDisplayS": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Light","lineHeight":79,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","fontSize":72},
  "fontDisplayM": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Light","lineHeight":90,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","fontSize":82,"letterSpacing":0,"paragraphSpacing":0},
  "fontDisplayL": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Light","lineHeight":113,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","fontSize":103,"letterSpacing":0,"paragraphSpacing":0},
  "fontDisplayXl": {"fontFamily":"Metric","fontWeight":"Light","lineHeight":146,"textDecoration":"none","textCase":"none","fontSize":133},
  "fontSpacingDefault": 2,
  "fontSpacingS": 2,
  "colorBackground": "#111111ff",
  "colorOnBackground100": "#3b3b3bff",
  "colorOnBackground200": "#9e9e9eff",
  "colorOnBackground300": "#e8e8e8ff",
  "colorSurface100": "#262626ff",
  "colorSurface200": "#303030ff",
  "colorSurface300": "#3b3b3bff",

not trying a lot of things

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
